# Floating button and Activity/Fragment architecture

Tags: android, architecture, floating-action-button, android-appbarlayout, coordinator-layout

I am trying to find the best architecture implemeting Floating Button. This is my scenary:

I have a base activity that has coordinatorlayout,appbarlayout, toolbar, floating button and a frame layout to use it with fragments.
The first fragment contains a view pager and tab layout and each tab is an other fragment (recyclerview). 
The problem is that when I click an item I want to open another fragment, because I dont want to have a lot of activities implemeting the same stuff. The problem is that I don't want to have that floating button on the new fragment that I am opening.

Which is the best approach?

1. Having two activities one with the floating button and other without
2. Hide and show the floating button depeding on which fragment I am.
3. Other approach will be fantastic..

The idea of this is learn architecure, any suggestion will be excelent for me

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `Floating Action Button (FAB)` is not implemented in one of the fragments which would be one way to hide it when the second one shows up. The easiest way would be to call `.setVisibility(View.GONE)` on the FAB when you start the second Fragment and set it visible again when you go back to the first Fragment.

If you add the FAB to the first fragment then it should disappear with the whole fragment when you switch to the second one. If your activity needs to handle the `onClick` event of the FAB implement an interface in the fragment for it.

Having two activities just for hiding a FAB would be way to much. If you add the FAB to the fragment you don't have to worry that it is visible when the second fragment is shown and the performance loss of the extra function call shouldn't matter cause you aren't going to do it like 100 times per minute.

Comment: Cool, the problem is that if i add the floating button on each fragment I am having problems with the coordinator layout because the frame layout has app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" . The problem is that just a half of button is being show, once you scroll you see the entire button.

Comment: (https://guides.codepath.com/android/floating-action-buttons) On this side they have some simple examples of implementing a floating button and one is in a scrollview. I don't know how you implemented your FAB but try <code>app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" </code> that should put the button in the right bottom corner. The full xml impementation can you see in the examples. Hope this works haven't used scolling view with FAB myself til now actually.